# How can I find the correlation (if any) between performance and equipment type?

Tags: correlation, python

I have a dataframe of car race data that looks something like this:

```
df.head()

+-----+-------------+----------+--------------------+
| idx | race_number | car_type | finishing_position |
+-----+-------------+----------+--------------------+
| 0   | 1           | ford     | 1                  |
+-----+-------------+----------+--------------------+
| 1   | 1           | ford     | 3                  |
+-----+-------------+----------+--------------------+
| 2   | 1           | renault  | 2                  |
+-----+-------------+----------+--------------------+
| 3   | 2           | ford     | 3                  |
+-----+-------------+----------+--------------------+
| 4   | 2           | ford     | 2                  |
+-----+-------------+----------+--------------------+
| 5   | 2           | renault  | 1                  |
+-----+-------------+----------+--------------------+
| ... | ...         | ...      | ...                |
+-----+-------------+----------+--------------------+
```

How can I figure out if there is any correlation (positive or negative) between the finishing position of cars of the same type?

Comment: Correlation is defined for numeric variables, which yours are not, so you will have to think of something else.

Comment: @user2974951 I'm looking for correlation in `finishing_position` between cars of the same type. `finishing_position` is an integer value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `finishing_position` is indeed composed of integers, but they may just as well have been characters a, b, and c. So they are not really numerical i.e. in interval or ratio form.

What you could do is treat this variable as ordinal, since it does at least have some sort of order to it, and then estimate the Spearman correlation coefficient.

Comment: Excellent point, this worked.